# How I can format background colour for a row based on first word from string

Tags: google-sheets

```
       A       B         C
1     xxx     xxx   Text1, Text2
2     xxx     xxx   Text2, Text1
```

On above example I would like change background colour for `row1` based on cell `C1` and only first string of text `Text1`, so on `row2` I would like have other background based on cell `C2` and only first string of text `Text2`

I'm using at this moment something like this:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(REGEXEXTRACT($F:$F, "Text1")), 1,0)
```

so I have as many I need similar formulas but doesn't work good, changing background to formula order hierarchy. For example if my `Text1` formula is on top then `row2` will get same background.

Here is my testing spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s31_n-vgxQ5x8FJHH7xyX41H0HUsNOX1HcIHid0q8-w/edit?usp=sharing

Please help,

Pawel

Answer (score 0):

You may extract the first word assuming there is a comma in a text:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[^,]+")`

and result:

```
Text            Result
Text1, Text2    Text1
Text2, Text1    Text2
```

Regex finds all chars not being a comma from a string. Reference:

https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt

Comment: I have try work around this but with no success. Still don't understood how to make it works. Thanks for reply and help. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s31_n-vgxQ5x8FJHH7xyX41H0HUsNOX1HcIHid0q8-w/edit?usp=sharing